# Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing my first facebook app, which includes creating a new album and posting photos to the user wall. By learning through facebook documentation and few tutorial and came up this code, but I am getting following error with it.

`Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating application. Thrown in /home/base_facebook.php on line 1106`

Plus: I don’t know if it matters or not, but when I am printing out the

`echo $facebook->getUser();`

variable it giving me ‘0’ in return even though user (which in this case is myself) is logged in.

Kindly help me through this.

*Code:*

```
$config = array(
'appId'  => '3663250024856',
'secret' => 'b14ac6d2b7dbdtyb259599b06983e881',
'fileUpload' => true,
'cookie' => true
);


        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        echo "USER STATUS:".$facebook->getUser();
        $facebook -> setFileUploadSupport(true);

        $album_details = array('message' => 'Album desc', 'name' => 'Album name');
        $create_album = $facebook -> api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

        $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

        $photo_details = array('message' => 'Photo message');
        $file = "temp/".$imageName;
        $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

        $upload_photo = $facebook -> api('/' . $album_uid . '/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the user is logged in, the user needs to give permission to your app before you can make api calls.

Basically the flow for user authentication using facebook php sdk should be like this:

1. Detect whether the user is logged in and given permission to your app.
2. If he hasn't given permission, redirect him to the login and application permission page. After logging in and giving permission, he'll be redirected back again to your application page.

   Otherwise, show the content of your app, make api calls,...

Here is a modified sample code from the php sdk's documentation page to handle authentication that should work if you just modify the appId, appSecret and redirect_uri:

```
<?php
require_once 'fb_php_sdk/facebook.php';

$appId = 'your_app_id';
$appSecret = 'your_app_secret';

// Create your Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook( 
    array(
      'appId'  => $appId,
      'secret' => $appSecret,
    'fileUpload' => true,
    'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) 
{
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) 
{
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 
else 
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                            array(
                                'canvas' => 1,
                                'fbconnect' => 0,
                                'scope' => '',//these are the extended permissions you will need for your app, add/remove according to your requirement
                                'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/test_app_azk/',//this is the redirect uri where user will be redirected after allow,
                                ));                                       
}

if ($user)
{
    //show the content of your app
    //make api calls
    var_dump($user_profile);
}
else
{
    //redirect user to loginUrl
    echo "<script>parent.location = '".$loginUrl."';</script>";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if i am not wrong the permission is given when user first authorized the app.. user doesn't need to give permission every time he uses the app or does he? in case of the first case user has authorized the app already? kindly clear it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. User needs to give permission only when he visits your app for the first time. Afterwards, redirecting user to the loginUrl will take him back to the app page with a valid access_token which will enable the app to make api calls.

Comment: can you plz guide me how can i retrieve 'access_token' after being authenticated and redirected to the app page?

Comment: Actually you don't need to worry much about handling 'access_token' yourself. The php sdk handles this stuff. Whenever you make an api call using $facebook->api(), the access_token is used by the sdk. What do you currently get when making this call: $facebook->api('/me')

Comment: i found the way out of the earlier error, but now i am getting this one: `OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`.. why i shld do?

Comment: Have you tried using the sample code I had given which redirects the user to loginUrl when needed? I have just tried that code with a newly created appId and secret and it is making the $facebook->api('/me') call successfully without any OAuthException. Of course you will need to put appropriate 'redirect_uri' in that code. It should be your apps url like: http://apps.facebook.com/your_app_namespace/

Comment: your code is just redirecting me to the first main app page specified in redirect_uri.

Comment: yeah and it also shows the content of $user_profile which is the result of $facebook->api('/me'). It should show your account information which proves that you can make further api calls. What are you getting in the $user_profile variable?

Answer (score 4):

The best working solution I've found in the web. Add the below code at the top of your php page:

```
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";   
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "YOUR_URL";


   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might lie within the else statement. Instead of using else use if(!user). That should fix the issue.